# Get events in full calendar given dates from DTP on button click. Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, calendar, fullcalendar

```
<p> From: </p>
<input type="date" id="from-date" class="form-control"/>
<p> To: </p>
<input type="date" id="to-date" class="form-control"/>

<p> From: </p>
<input type="date" id="from-date-copy" class="form-control"/>
<p> To: </p>
<input type="date" id="to-date-copy" class="form-control"/>
<input type="button" id="copy">
```

Hi guys, I have this first 2 date time pickers to set the span of dates to get in the FullCalendar, and the other set of 2 date time pickers where to copy the events.

Example I have..

1/13/2016 as start date
and 
1/15/2016 as end date << **DATE / EVENTS TO COPY**

AND 1/20/2016 and 1/22/2016 <-- **WHERE TO COPY**

I will get all events from 1/13/2016 and 1/15/2016 and transfer the events to 1/20/2016 and 1/22/2016. Please help.

First picture:
[image]

Second picture:
[image]

I used this code :

```
function bindCopyEventsButton() {
    $("#copy").click(function(event) {
        var eventsInDay;
        var eventsHolder = [];
        var startDate = $("#from-date").val();
        var endDate = new Date($("#to-date").val());

        var whereToCopyStartDate = new Date($('#from-date-copy').val());
        var whereToCopyEndDate = new Date($('#to-date-copy').val());
        var whereToCopyStart = whereToCopyStartDate.getDate();
        var whereToCopyEnd = whereToCopyEndDate.getDate();

        var e1start = new Date(startDate);
        var e1end = endDate == null ? e1start : endDate;

        for (var d = e1start; d <= e1end; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {

            //Get all events in the day
            eventsInDay = getEventsInDay(d);

            //For copy and paste. Will be used later. It's currently performing cut and paste
            //eventsHolder.push(eventsInDay);

            //Iterate all events in the day for updating
            for(var e = 0; e < eventsInDay.length; e++) {

                //Check if still applicable
                if(whereToCopyStart <= whereToCopyEnd){ 

                    //Get start hour of the event
                    var startTimeHour = eventsInDay[e].start._i.getHours();
                    console.log("startTimeHour : " + startTimeHour);

                    //Get end hour of the event
                    var endTimeHour = eventsInDay[e].end._i.getHours();
                    console.log("endTimeHour : " + endTimeHour);

                    //Get start date of the event
                    var x = eventsInDay[e].start._i.getDate();
                    console.log("Start date.getDate : " + x);
                    //Get end date of the event
                    var y = eventsInDay[e].end._i.getDate();
                    console.log("End date.getDate : " + y);


                    //Set start date of the event to the value of the from date
                    eventsInDay[e].start._i.setDate(whereToCopyStart); 

                    //If the start date and end date are the same use same end date. else start date + 1
                    if(x == y){ 
                        eventsInDay[e].end._i.setDate(whereToCopyStart);
                    } else {
                        eventsInDay[e].end._i.setDate(whereToCopyStart + 1);
                    }

                    console.log("Event GET START DATE : " + eventsInDay[e].start._i.getDate());
                    console.log("Event GET END DATE : " + eventsInDay[e].end._i.getDate());

                    //Set the start hours of event
                    eventsInDay[e].start._i.setHours(startTimeHour);

                    //Set the end hours of event
                    eventsInDay[e].end._i.setHours(endTimeHour);

                    //Update Calendar
                    $('#preferred-schedule').fullCalendar('updateEvent',  eventsInDay[e]);

                    //Add 1 to the  **where to copy** start date
                    whereToCopyStart = (whereToCopyStart + 1);
                }
            }
        }           
    });
}

function getEventsInDay(date) {
    return $('#preferred-schedule').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(evt) {
        if (date >= evt.start && date <= evt.end) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

I think I'm getting the right info. but again. The `clientEvents` doesn't get the events in the day. and the `updateEvent` doesn't reflect on the FullCalendar. But when I'm debugging I think I'm getting the right infos based on the logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value comparisons are not completely correct (you will need to do some date manipulations), but I think this is kind of what you're looking for, using the [`clientEvents`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/) and [`updateEvent`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/updateEvent/) methods of [`FullCalendar`](http://fullcalendar.io/):

```
//Find all the events that match the criteria
var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(evt){
    if(evt.start >= $('#from-date').val() && evt.end <= $('#to-date').val()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});

//Loop through the events and update them
for(var e = 0; e < events.length; e++){
    events[e].start = $('#from-date-copy');
    events[e].end = $('#to-date-copy');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', events[e]);
}
```

Hopefully this gives you a push in the right direction.

> **Maybe Helpful Hint**
>
> To see how the `clientEvents` function works and what format it
>   returns data in, you can use the fullCalendar demo
>   (http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.6.0/demos/agenda-views.html).
>   Open Chrome DevTools and use this function: `var events =
>   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(evt){return
>   true;});` then print out `events`.

Comment: May I ask what is the if statement for?

Comment: The function passed to `clientEvents` should only return true for events that match your start and end date criteria. All other events return false so they do not get included in the resulting events array.

Comment: It doesn't get all events in one day. When example I have 2 events in one day. Only the first event is saved in the object.

Comment: @EdwardBeringuela According to the documentation for `clientEvents` it should use the function to filter through all the events. Did you try debugging and see if it runs through the function more than once?

Comment: It doesn't run twice when I have 2 events. See edits**

Comment: @EdwardBeringuela What does your `getEventsInDay` function look like?

Comment: I've got a new logic flow do you want me to change the whole edit?

Comment: I think I currently have the right logic, but the updateEvents is not working now.

Comment: @EdwardBeringuela Sure, let's see what you've got.

Comment: function getEventsInDay(date) {
  return $('#preferred-schedule').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(evt) {
     if (date >= evt.start && date <= evt.end) {
      return true;
     }
    });
 }

Comment: Changes saved*! Thanks !